# What techniques should I be using to preserve light sources?

Tags: amnesia-the-dark-descent

So I am playing *Amnesia: The Dark Decent* and figured out pretty quickly that light is an important commodity, as you can use it to recover your sanity, amongst other things.

So I've been wondering, How do you preserve your light sources? Specifically, I mean coal, oil and other things that generates light.

For example, this is what I've been doing when I arrive in a new place that I never seen before:

1. Place a light source (such as a torch) near the exit, in case you get lost.
2. Find a closed place (where you can hide in case of monster), close the doors, give that room some light and start visiting the rest of the place.
3. Make sure you get back to this place often to recover sanity.
4. Save your oil at maximum (for Enigmas you can't find out, when the creature is coming, when you have to recover your sanity quick).

Is this a good technique? Is there a better way of preserving light sources whilst not compromising safety?

Comment: Very nice help, though i think this question can not really be answered, i think your solution is the best. So you can basically answer your own question (by the way i will use your trick :D )

Comment: "Save your oil at maximum" — you mean loading up the lamp with oil? I doubt this is a good idea since there are some oil containers which add oil directly to the lamp rather than your inventory.